# Magento SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry WHEN INSTERT

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a problem with magento. when order placed everything goes through except the customer gets user friendly error but I get this sqlstate error.

I read the mysql_pdo_log and the error comes after this query which I have tried with console giving same error

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_tmp` SELECT
`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`entity_id`, 
`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`customer_group_id`, 
`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`website_id`, 
`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`tax_class_id`, 
`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`orig_price` AS `price`, 
`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`price` AS `final_price`, 
`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`min_price`, 
`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`max_price`, 
`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`tier_price`, 
`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`group_price` FROM 
`catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`
```

the error is

```
EXCEPTION 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '455-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'' in F:\Projects\html2\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228
```

455 is the product ID which is simple product associated to a configurable product.

and this is how catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp table looks like.

[image]

Somehow magento is not able to empty this table or something else is going on. When the order placed the inventory stays 1 but status changes to out of stock...

Thank you

Comment: you're trying to insert a duplicate record. but since your error doesn't say WHICH table this was being done on, we can't really help you.

Comment: how can I find which table does that? is there way to find it? thanks.

Comment: the error gives you a line number (`:228`). go look there.

Comment: Come on, @Marc its just a line in the *driver*. If you really think that anything can be found in the code, look at the stack trace in the older edition.

Comment: whoops. no older edition found. correcting...